# Cassandra Clustering : Importance of port

Tags: cassandra

Can anyone explain the importance of using same ports across all nodes in Cassandra cluster. How the clustering established ? (Because of same port across the cluster or using a common seed names across the cluster) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The clustering is established by the `cluster_name` and seed setting in your Cassandra config file (`cassandra.yaml`).  You don't need to use the same ports across the cluster. In fact, you can run several cassandra nodes on the same vm with different ports.  Cassandra uses Gossip for internode communication. You can read more about it [here](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ArchitectureGossip).

Comment: Hi, I have tested a two node(in different machine) cluster with different Storage port (Other ports are same ), but  found not clustered.

Comment: Did you configure the seeds? See http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/initialize/initializeSingleDS.html on how to configure the cluster

Comment: Yes, Given Both nodes names in both nodes seed configuration to avoid confusion.